# SQL query generated by LINQ TO SQL statement

Tags: linq-to-sql

How would i know the SQL statement generated by my Linq to sql query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could see the SQL statement by using the toString() statement.

```
var customers = from cust in Customers
        select cust;

Console.WriteLine(customers.ToString());
```

or you could do something like this.

```
DataContext context = new DataContext(...);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
context.Log = writer;

var customers = from cust in Customers
        select cust;

Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
```

Comment: Wow, who knew. I've been using LINQ for a couple of years now and never had any idea that Query.ToString would return the SQL command.

Answer (score 3):

Use [LINQ to SQL Debugger Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx).

Alternatively, you can set `dataContext.Log` property to `Console.Out` or something and the SQL statement, along with actual parameter values will be written out to that stream.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to check the query http://www.linqpad.net/