# LINQ to SQL displayed in console mode app

Tags: c#, sql, linq, console

I have written a console mode app to test `LINQ` to `SQL` queries.

When I run the console mode app the generated `SQL` is being diaplyed in the console window. I have not changed any settings so why is this being output?

It is very handy and has helped me to debug my `LINQ` queries but I have no idea as to how this generated `SQL` is being output.

Please can someone enlighten me?

Comment: post your code first

Comment: I bet you set your `db.Log` property to `Console.Write;`, you can disable it by setting it to `null` (`db.Log = null;` - or `#IF !DEBUG db.Log = null; #ENDIF`) This setting is in many internet examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have used the `ToString` method on your query result. For example suppose you have this query:-

```
var query = from cust in db.Customer
            select cust;
```

And you convert this linq query to string like this and print:-

```
string strQuery query.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(strQuery); //This will print the generated SQL query.
```

Please note there are many ways to check the generated SQL. For instance check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577231/sql-query-generated-by-linq-to-sql-statement).

Comment: this or `db.Log = Console.Write;` (as in many examples on internet - and [ctrl]+[c] [ctr]+[v] by accident. Hard to say without src :) )

Comment: @Jan'splite'Kondelík - Yup there is a possibility :)