# Linq to Sql - Incorrect syntax by keyword 'IS'

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to order my query by null values on one column and then by another column as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461479/linq-order-by-null-column-where-order-is-ascending-and-nulls-should-be-last) post.

```
_ctx.Leads.Include(a => a.LeadAttachments)
    .Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filter))
    .OrderBy(a=>a.AcceptedOn.HasValue)
    .ThenByDescending(a => a.AssignedOn)
    .Skip(offSet)
    .Take(12)
    .ToList()
```

I get this error when adding `.OrderBy(a=>a.AcceptedOn.HasValue)`

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
>
> Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Both my order by columns are of type`Nullable<DateTime>`.

What is wrong with this query? Is there a better way of sorting?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @vamsi answer, I am not having this error. Now I need this to sort like the following:
All records that have a `null` value for `AcceptedOn` should be first
All records that have a value for both dates should be sorted by `AssignedOn` not `AcceptedOn`
**Is this possible?**

Comment: Can you show what is the sql generated by this please?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: I believe you just replace `ToList` with `ToString`

Comment: Have you tried **.OrderBy(a=>a.AcceptedOn.Value)** instead?

Comment: @MB - Just put a `ToString()` instead of the `ToList() - see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

Comment: @StinkyTowel That would be a different ordering.

Comment: @MB what version of SQL server are you using? Is it a SQL server 2008?

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: @GiladGreen @Igor `.ToString()` did not work

Comment: @MB - in the link I added they also say this: `ToTraceString`

Comment: @MB Try `.OrderBy( a => a.AcceptedOn != null )`

Comment: I don;t have the classes needed for that method. It was for ado.net

Comment: @MB - using [ToString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577231/sql-query-generated-by-linq-to-sql-statement) should work. Please show how you tried to use it

Comment: @MB - your update is a follow-up question. And as you said - for your original question vamsi's answer did the trick

Comment: Does `AssignedOn` also contain null values?

Comment: It could. generally doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment:

> but what i really want is first all null acceptedOn and then rest ordered by AssignedOn. Is that possible

```
_ctx.Leads.Include(a => a.LeadAttachments)
        .Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filter))
        .OrderByDescending(a=> a.AcceptedOn == null 
            ? DateTime.MaxValue 
            : a.AssignedOn == null 
                ? a.AcceptedOn 
                : a.AssignedOn)
        .Skip(offSet)
        .Take(12)
        .ToList();
```

---

Sort priority in code explained

1. Records with a `null` value for `AcceptedOn` appear at the top
2. Records that have a value for both `AcceptedOn` **AND** `AssignedOn` will be sorted by `AssignedOn` in descending order
3. Remaining records that only have a value for `AcceptedOn` will be sorted last in descending order

Comment: @GiladGreen - they are both datetime fields. Op wants all null entries first and then sorted on AssignedOn descending. This should do that I think.

Comment: Looking good, but any way to sort the `AccpetedOn == null` records thenBy `AssignedOn`?

Comment: @MB - sure, just take that one step further (see update) with another null check. This assumes you want to sort on either type descending.

Comment: No, like this. If `AcceptedON == null` then by maxvalue then `assingedon` else by `assignedon`

Comment: @MB - you wrote `assignedon ` x2, in your comment. Which one of those is actually `AssignedOn` and which is `AcceptedOn` ?

Comment: thos with acceptedOn value and thosse without should both be sorted by `assignedOn` as well

Comment: @MB - What I have above is: 1. Empty `AcceptedOn` first 2. If `AssignedOn` has a value then sort by that next (descending) 3. Sort the rest on `AcceptedOn` (descending)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125194/discussion-between-igor-and-m-b).

Comment: Got it! used original ternary and then added a `ThenByDescneding(a=>a.AssignedOn)`. THis ordered everything then by  the `assignedOn` column

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works

```
 _ctx.Leads.Include(a => a.LeadAttachments)
        .Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filter))
        .OrderBy(a=>a.AcceptedOn ?? DateTime.MinValue)
        .ThenByDescending(a => a.AssignedOn)
        .Skip(offSet)
        .Take(12)
        .ToList()
```

Comment: this works but what i really want is first all null `acceptedOn` and then rest ordered by `AssignedOn`. Is that possible

Comment: @MB that is exactly what my answer is doing. If acceptedon is null it defaults it to datetime.minimum value which is 00.00.0000 so those records are first in the list followed by next sort order

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using .HasValue, which returns a bool, when you should be using .Value, which returns the actual value if not null.

Try this, I'm sure it will work...

```
.OrderBy(a=>a.AcceptedOn.Value)
```

Comment: You don't need to add the `.Value`. you can just use the column itself

Comment: This is not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working perfectly for me

```
_ctx.Leads.Include(a => a.LeadAttachments)
    .Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(filter))
    .OrderByDescending(a=> a.AcceptedOn == null 
        ? DateTime.MaxValue 
        : a.AssignedOn).ThenByDescending(a=>a.AssignedOn)
    .Skip(offSet)
    .Take(12)
    .ToList();
```

Explanation:

First sort: get null `AcceptedOn` first
Then: order all records by `AssignedOn`